# Connection not opening in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle-sqldeveloper

For my C# application i need to connect with oracle database. I have always used the same connection and it worked perfect with other applications. Added the same reference i always used: Oracle.DataAcces

This here is the problem and i dont know how to fix it.

> An exception of type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException' occurred in Monime_V2.0.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: External component has thrown an exception.

This is what i use to connect:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

// Oracle 
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

namespace Monime_V2._0
{
    public class Database
    {
         protected OracleConnection conn;
         public OracleConnection Conn
        {
        get
        {
            return this.conn;
        }
    }

    public Database()
    {
        //dbconnectie
        this.conn = new OracleConnection();
        string pcn = "dbi284945"; //login
        string pw = "HGD7dh8daa"; //password
        this.conn.ConnectionString = "User Id=" + pcn + ";Password=" + pw + ";Data Source=" + "//192.168.15.50:1521/fhictora" + ";";
    }
```

Here goes it all wrong:

```
private List<Account> GetListAccounts()
    {
        List<Account> listA = new List<Account>();

        string sql = "select * from MT_ACCOUNT";
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, this.conn);

        try
        {
            this.conn.Open(); // <-- This line of code sends me to the exception catcher
            OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: So what does the exception say? Do you want us to *guess* what your problem is?

Comment: Can you please put a breakpoint inside the Catch() function and see the exception?

Comment: The first quotet block i have posted in my question is all i get. So yea, i hope you guys could guess what the problem might be

Comment: As the error message suggests: "Please review the stack trace for more information about the error". There is most likely inner exceptions which will give more details on what went wrong.

Comment: Don't rethrow the exception like that, you'll lose the stack trace. Use `throw;`!

Comment: And throwing a new exception which contains only the message of the exception actually thrown makes no sense and is really really bad practice.

Comment: Are you using the same machine you always use? If not, this might be the cause: http://forums.asp.net/t/1250328.aspx?+External+component+has+thrown+an+exception+in+ODP+net

Comment: Yes, same machine. I used throw; instead, but it still wont open.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to troubleshoot this error message is to use an OracleException:

```
try
{
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
}
catch (OracleException ex)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Record is not inserted into the database table.");
  Console.WriteLine("Exception Message: " + ex.Message);
  Console.WriteLine("Exception Source: " + ex.Source);
}
```

You  get a more descriptive diagnosis of what the problem is. For example instead of this unhelpful generic error message:

> An exception of type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException'

I get this :

> {"ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GETCLIENTBYID'\nORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored"}

Answer (score -1):

You should try this code for `public database()` :

```
public Database()
{
        //dbconnectie
        this.conn = new OracleConnection();
        string pcn = "dbi284945"; //login
        string pw = "HGD7dh8daa"; //password
        string connection = string.Format("User Id ={0};password={1};Data Source=//192.168.15.50:1521/fhictora;",pcn,pw);
        this.conn.ConnectionString = connection;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have the oracle managment open when you run your code?